# How to send a message similar to "link preview" format?

Tags: android, whatsapp

After searching too much on the internet, I found nothing than this

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

But this is sending a simple plain message only.

I want to send message like this

[image: WhatsApp link preview]

I want the message to have a header in bold with some light gray background and my app name below it.

Comment: That is just how WhatsApp renders links. If you send a url it *should* render it the same way.

Answer (score 0):

If you send link it will automatically create it's preview. see https://github.com/LeonardoCardoso/Android-Link-Preview for more info

Comment: I don't having website. I want to create preview from my app data and preview has to  to deep link to my app